# Compare struct with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, struct, uiimage

I have below struct

```
struct Contact: Equatable {
    let name: String?
    let number: String
    let image: UIImage?
}

func ==(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.number == rhs.number && lhs.image == rhs.image
}
```

I use the above function to compare two structs. But it fails for comparing image. Even if the structs have same image, it fails. What do I miss here?

**EDIT:**

Based on Duncan's comment, I modified to function to

```
func ==(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
    var imagesAreEqual = false
    if let lhsImage = lhs.image, let rhsImage = rhs.image {
        imagesAreEqual = lhsImage.isEqual(rhsImage)
    } else if lhs.image == nil && rhs.image == nil {
        imagesAreEqual = true
    }

    return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.number == rhs.number && imagesAreEqual
}
```

Still condition fails.

Comment: Do they both reference the same UIImage object? Or two different instances that just look exactly the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs on `UIImage` in Xcode, they say:

> The isEqual(_:) method is the only reliable way to determine whether
>   two images contain the same image data.
>
> The image objects you create may be different from each other, even
>   when you initialize them with the same cached image data. The only way
>   to determine their equality is to use the isEqual(_:) method, which
>   compares the actual image data.

So rewrite your == function to use isEqual to compare the images:

```
func ==(lhs: Contact, rhs: Contact) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name && 
      lhs.number == rhs.number && 
      lhs.image.isEqual(rhs.image)
}
```

Comment: The `==` overload for `NSObject` calls `isEqual(_:)`, so this shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Hamish, that quote is lifted right from the Swift docs on UIImage, and it even gives an example of using if `imageA == imageB` with the comment "// Incorrect! Direct object comparisons may not work."

Comment: @DuncanC Huh, that is indeed curious. My gut feeling is that they've incorrectly transferred that from the Objective-C docs on `UIImage`, which indeed *would* be correct in saying that using `==` isn't a reliable way of comparing images. But [you can see here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSObject.swift#L166) that the Swift overload of `==` for `NSObject` simply calls `isEqual(_:)` (you can also override `isEquals(_:)` and verify it for yourself).